# Resize PDF page and wrap text?

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, pdfsharp

Is it possible to change the size of a page inside a PDF document without resizing all of its content? I want all text to wrap their content according to the new size.

I haven't been able to find any info regarding this. Seeing how PDF libraries work when writing to text, I guess it's not possible, but maybe there is a way around it.

I'm mainly looking for some .Net code, PDFSharp, iTextSharp, PDF Clown, or any other .Net library is fine, if some tool already allows this I would be interested as well. Of course, some Java iText code may be fine as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The internals of a PDF document don't have a concept of "sentences" or "paragraphs" so what you are looking for isn't really possible short of extracting the text, guessing at those concepts and creating a brand new document. Libraries such as iTextSharp and PDF Clown have abstractions that make working with text easier but ultimately they all come down to PDF commands that draw out characters or lines of text. What we think of as a paragraph is just a bunch of vertically-spaced lines of text within the PDF. The libraries perform the heavy lifting of calculating how to turn "paragraphs" into those lines of text and once that happens there is no more "paragraph". In order to "flow" text we would need these concepts so you can see why this wouldn't work.

There *might* be some libraries that offer this but I haven't seem them and ultimately they would be guessing, too.

Comment: When I saw how the text is drawn, I immediately realized the lack you talk about, but seeing all the effort put into libraries like iText maybe there was some automated method for this. I wonder if Acrobat Reader Pro allows for something like this.

Comment: If you ever find something that does this let me know, I have a couple of uses for it, too! But I can only think of the edge cases that aren't defined if this were actually implemented. For instance, what happens if reflow causes a new page, is it just blank or is there a template it should be based on? What about headers and footers, those should probably just be moved instead of reflowed. What about alignment, left vs centered? The latter is actually just left-aligned with extra character spacing. These are the things that make me think that there isn't anything that can automate this.

Comment: I know there would be a lot of formatting to take into consideration, and a lot of cases where you'd surely end with a useless PDF, but I wouldn't need anything extremely complex. This would automate the conversion of several PDFs, if some of them doesn't look near as expected, I'd make a properly resized version of that PDF by hand. Since these PDFs come from Word files, I've also thought of changing the width of the doc files themselves, and generate a new PDF from there, but I've yet to settle on this.